# what is version of spark and pyspark compatible with python 3.10

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I built a virtual environment and I installed these version of packages. it throws an error as follows and it is because of not being compatible packages, what is the best version of spark and Pyspark which is compatible with my version of Python?

```
java version: openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20 
spark version : 2.4.6
Pyspark version: 2.4.6
Python version : 3.10
```

The code  :

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

The error :

```
Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.isEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM
```

Comment: really old spark version. try upgrading to a 3.x release

Answer (score 0):

From spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/#downloading):

> Spark runs on Java 8, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API,
> Spark 2.4.6 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala
> version (2.12.x).

You should downgrade java version from 11 to 8.

Comment: I do it, but It still show it to me the same version.. I do it in my virtual env